# JasperReports Server: ERROR SubstitutionVariable No getter method?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In our *Tomcat* logs in on *JasperReports Server 5.0.1* we are getting this error on a few reports.

I have checked the reports and couldn't find anything that might cause this error.

There is no parameter with the name "campus_id" in the XML or any input control of these reports

Any idea what could cause this error ? or how to fix it

```
2013-11-06 12:15:55,119 ERROR SubstitutionVariable,pool-24-thread-5:194 - No get
ter method getCampus_id for campus:campus_id for class com.jaspersoft.commons.da
taset.expr.Literal
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing property: campus_id
        at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.SubstitutionVariable.getProperty(
SubstitutionVariable.java:111)
    at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.varRef(Da
taSetExpressionParser.java:1910)
        at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.term(Data
SetExpressionParser.java:1539)
        at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.multDivEx
```

**Note:** I am using: *iReport 5.0.0*, *JR Server 5.0.1*, *Windows 7 Pro 64bit*, *Tomcat 7*

Comment: Do you have the field with such name? It is better to post the *jrxml* file

Comment: The error was being caused by the campus parameter, I still don't know why, I just removed the param